# iPhone 5 changes itself to a black theme with white and blue writing

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5 keeps changing itself to a black theme with white and blue fonts but then defaults back to white. I want the black them but have no idea where that is and how to turn on as the phone just does it itself.

It's the whole OS. Not safari. I have have screen shots of my contact list, missed calls and a full contact.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this for the whole OS or safari? if it's just safari, it's black when you use private browsing and goes back when you revert to normal browsing.

Comment: Could you maybe take a screenshot (by pressing the home and power button at the same time) and post it here? This might help us understand what's going on.

Comment: Once you have screen shots, you can upload them to http://imgur.com and edit the links into your question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Aboofqf
http://imgur.com/UgO8c54 Here are a few extra screen shots.

Answer (score 3):

This would be explained entirely by a change to your accessibility settings to "Invert Colors".

You can change that back in Settings->General->Accessibility.